# Bool is being returned correctly but still won't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python.

I am wanting to check the input of the user and check if the input is accepted. The method is called 'check_input' and i call this method in the 'running' methods 3rd line. I pass it a string and bool variable.

I then want to return the inputAccepted value and then do something with it depending on its value.

I have used breakpoints and the bool itself is changed correctly but when the code leaves the 'check_input' method the bool 'inputAccepted' is forgotten.

What am i doing wrong?

My theory is that the bool isn't accessible outside the method?

```
import random
import collections
import re

codeLength = 4
guessesRemaining = 10
inputAccepted = False

welcomeMessage = 'Welcome to Mastermind. Try and guess the code by using the following letters:\n\nA B C D E F \n\nThe code will NOT contain more than 1 instance of a letter.\n\nAfter you have entered your guess press the "ENTER" key.\nYou have a total of'
print(welcomeMessage, guessesRemaining, 'guesses.\n')


def gen_code(codeLength):
    symbols = ('ABCDEF')
    code = random.sample(symbols, k=codeLength)
    return str(code)

code = gen_code(codeLength)
print(code)
counted = collections.Counter(code)

def check_input(guess, inputAccepted):
    if not re.match("[A-F]", guess): #Only accepts the letters from A-F
        print("Please only use the letters 'ABCDEF.'")
        inputAccepted = False
        return (guess, inputAccepted)

    else:
        inputAccepted = True
        return (guess, inputAccepted)

def running():
    guess = input() #Sets the guess variable to what the user has inputted
    guess = guess.upper() #Converts the guess to uppercase
    check_input(guess, inputAccepted) #Checks if the letter the user put in is valid

    print(guess)
    print(inputAccepted)

    if inputAccepted == True:
        guessCount = collections.Counter(trueGuess)
        close = sum(min(counted[k], guessCount[k]) for k in counted)
        exact = sum(a == b for a,b in zip(code, guess))
        close -= exact
        print('\n','Exact: {}. Close: {}. '.format(exact,close))
        return exact != codeLength
    else:
        print("Input wasnt accepted")

for attempt in range(guessesRemaining):
    if not running():
        print('Done')
        break
    else:
        print('Guesses remaining:', guessesRemaining - 1 - attempt, '\n')

else:
        print('Game over. The code was {}'.format(''.join(code)))
```

Thank you very much

Comment: check_input has a return value, which you are not using. You may have intended to do something like guess, inputAccepted = check_input(guess, inputAccepted)

Comment: I think you need to have `InputAccepted = check_input(guess, inputAccepted)`. Also only return the bool value of InputAccepted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: or just rename the function to inputAccepted(guess) and call it within the if

Comment: @KennyOstrom Now i get the error 'UnboundLocalError....inputAccepted referenced before assignment'

Comment: When you set `inputAccepted = False` you aren't mutating the value of the reference passed in as you seem to expect. You are rebinding to a new bool object instead. It's unusual in Python to mutate your parameters (on purpose). usually multiple return values are simply done by packing into a tuple and unpacking at the caller, as in @KennyOstrom's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the return values of `check_input`, not look at the input values.

```
inputAccepted = check_input(guess)
```

There's also no reason for you to return your initial guess, so I would recommend rewriting the function `check_input`:

```
def check_input(guess):
    if not re.match("[A-F]", guess): #Only accepts the letters from A-F
        print("Please only use the letters 'ABCDEF.'")
        return False

    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand what my problem was now

Comment: The print side effect is not good practice. A more pythonic way would involve an exception, so you can later print the message. But that may be too much info for a new programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "inputAccepted" as global variable and formal argument in function check_input , change the argument name while defining function check_input, it may resolve your issue.